# cat or grep a html file to find specific text

Tags: bash

I am trying to use bash to parse and HTML file using grep.

The HTML won't change so I should be able to find the text easy enough.

The HTML will be like this, and I just want the number which will change each time the file changes:

```
<div class="total">
          900 files inspected,
          28301 offenses detected:
        </div>


grep -E '^<div class="total">.</div>' my_file.html
```

Ideally I just want to pull the number of offenses so in the example above it would be 28301.  I would like to assign it to a variable also.

Am I close?

Comment: A more *reliable* approach would be something like `tidy -asxml <my_file.html | xmlstarlet sel -N 'h=http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml' -t -m '//h:div[@class="total"]' -v './text()' -n` -- though the duplicates this is closed with are on point for what you asked for, as opposed to best/robust practices.

Comment: You might also be able to do the entire job without regular expressions or any external tools at all. `x="$(<file.html)"; x="${x%% offenses detected*}"; x="${x##*[^0-9]}"`

Comment: ghoti could you break this down as to whats happening in your example?

Comment: The syntax used above is described in detail in http://wiki.bash-hackers.org/syntax/pe, and also [covered in BashFAQ #100](http://mywiki.wooledge.org/BashFAQ/100#Removing_part_of_a_string).

Comment: Thanks for the link

Answer (score 1, accepted):

you can do a simple

```
a=$(grep -oP '(\d+)(?=\soffenses\sdetected)' abc);echo $a
```

will give:

```
28301
```

-o only gives the matching part of the line

-P uses perl regular expression in regex

abc is the name of the file

`(\d+)(?=\soffenses\sdetected)` in this reges we are just using positive lookahead to capture the require digits that are followed by a particular word

Comment: Thanks, makes sense I appreciate the explanation

Comment: Note that this depends on GNU `grep`, and specifically, a GNU `grep` compiled with the optional library libpcre.

Comment: To build on the GNU grep note from Charles, I'll point out that `grep` of any type is not actually *part of bash*, and varies from system to system. BSD systems may have an optional `pcregrep` binary installed with a `pcre` package the behaves similarly to `grep -P`, and macOS can get the same tool using Macports or Brew.

Comment: @CharlesDuffy absolutely valid point

Answer (score 0):

If you have GNU grep and GNU sed, you can do:

```
$ cat file | xargs | grep -Po '<div class=total>\K(.*?)</div>' | sed -E 's/<\/div>//; s/, /\n/'
 900 files inspected
28301 offenses detected:
```

If you have `ruby` available:

```
$ ruby -e 'puts readlines.join[/(?<=<div class="total">).+(?=<\/div>)/m].gsub(/^[ \t]+/m,"")' file 
900 files inspected,
28301 offenses detected:
```